# Annonymous pre and post survey results with different N values

Tags: survey

I have some survey data which was collected pre and post intervention. There is a drop off in the N value of respondents and the surveys were anonymous. Can I compare the pre and post at an aggregate level for changes even though the total N the percentages are based on is lower?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. It will depend on the type of missingness that you have - that is, is there a pattern by which people failed to follow up? For example, if your survey dealt with income and people who had higher incomes were less likely to respond, merely comparing pre- and post- results might lead to biased estimation.

What I might recommend is looking up different types of missingness, executing a few tests to try to assess how the missingness affects your data, and then attempt to appropriately overcome it.

However, if your N is reasonably large and the difference between your pre- N and post- N is 5% or less, I might recommend ignoring those data and executing the analysis on those who only did the pre- and post-surveys as any missing data techniques will only minority affect the outcome.

Comment: The question seems to suggest that information about connections or links between pre and post respondents was not collected.